# Onclick, Highlight only one list item in an Unordered list

Tags: javascript, html

I am following a code to make a quiz. I am building a function to highlight one list item and add a class to it.

```
function chooseAnswer(){
    answer.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((option)=> { 
    option.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        if(answer.querySelector('.selected')){
            let activeAnswer=answer.querySelector('.selected');
            activeAnswer.classList.remove('selected') 
        }else
        option.classList.add('selected')
})
```

The code is working but i do not understand the if condition from the source. Can someone help?

Comment: `if(answer.querySelector('.selected')){` condition simply checks if there are any elements, of children of the `answer` element, which have the `.selected` class - when there are no such elements `querySelector` returns `null`, therefore the condition is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`answer.querySelector('.selected')` will return the element with `.selected` class if it exists within the answer element.

If there is no `.selected` class within the answer element, it will return `null`.

In this code:

```
if(answer.querySelector('.selected')){
            ---
   }else
        option.classList.add('selected')
```

If the `if` condition is `null` that means there was no `.selected` element found. So the else block gets executed and it adds a `.selected` class to option.

But if there was a `.selected` class inside the answer element, the `if` condition would be truthy and would execute. Removing the `.selected` class.

Answer (score 0):

`if(answer.querySelector('.selected'))` statement is used to check whether there are any elements of `answer`, which have the `.selected` class

Comment: That isn't true. It checks whether it has descendant elements with such class

Comment: Hmm... needs some more explanation!

Comment: If i dont use the if condition and simply add the 'selected' class to 'option', the code highlights every option that is selected instead of only one

Comment: Because it adds class to every element on click. That's why `if` condition is necessary

Comment: @Shrey Bhangale - Is my understanding correct? : If condition removes class 'selected' for all list items and the else adds the class 'selected' to the current clicked list item

Comment: Yeah! `if` condition checks for `answer` elements with `selected` class. And if it is true then it removes the class of that element.